# How to flatten a table into one single row?

Tags: excel, powerquery, flatten, data-transform

Is it possible to convert the table from the left to the table on the right with PowerQuery?

Dont´t mind the labels except Table1, because they already exist in the destination.

In real life Table1 would be an Excel sheet and I have to flatten many of them (Table1 to Table50), each one into a single row:

[image]

I tried this:

1. Unpivoted the Aspect1/Aspect2 columns.
2. Merged the Attribute column with Aspect1/2 with the CAT1-5 column.
3. Transposed the table.
4. Promoted it as headers.

I got `Aspect1:Cat1; Aspect2:Cat1; Aspect2:Cat1; Aspect2:Cat2;...`

instead of `Aspect1:Cat1; Aspect1:Cat2; ... Aspect2:Cat1; Aspect2;Cat2...`

To clarify, I need: **Aspect1** merged with all the categories, then **Aspect2** with all the categories, and so on.

Comment: Unpivot the aspect columns and then transpose maybe? You can't have columns that span other columns like that though.

Comment: I don't need the aspects to span the categories, labels can be merged. I edited the post to clarify, hopefully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've got it from my suggestion if you just add a sorting step (see 4 below).

---

1. Unpivot the ASPECT columns
2. Concatenate ASPECT and CATEGORY as a new column
3. Remove ASPECT and CATEGORY column
4. Sort by the concatenated column
5. Transpose the table
6. Promote headers

Full M query:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WcnYMMVTSUTKxVAWSxuaqSrE6YEEjINfUECRoZAgXNAZxzUCChghBE5B2Y5AgQrcpkGdpChIzAwnGAgA=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [CATEGORY = _t, ASPECT1 = _t, ASPECT2 = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"CATEGORY", type text}, {"ASPECT1", Percentage.Type}, {"ASPECT2", Percentage.Type}}),
    #"Unpivoted Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"CATEGORY"}, "ASPECT", "Value"),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Unpivoted Columns", "ASPECT_CAT", each [ASPECT] & "; " & [CATEGORY], type text),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Added Custom",{"ASPECT_CAT", "Value"}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Removed Other Columns",{{"ASPECT_CAT", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Transposed Table" = Table.Transpose(#"Sorted Rows"),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Transposed Table", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"ASPECT1; CAT1", Percentage.Type}, {"ASPECT1; CAT2", Percentage.Type}, {"ASPECT1; CAT3", Percentage.Type}, {"ASPECT1; CAT4", Percentage.Type}, {"ASPECT1; CAT5", Percentage.Type}, {"ASPECT2; CAT1", Percentage.Type}, {"ASPECT2; CAT2", Percentage.Type}, {"ASPECT2; CAT3", Percentage.Type}, {"ASPECT2; CAT4", Percentage.Type}, {"ASPECT2; CAT5", Percentage.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type1"
```